# "I personally favor in-person over online courses." or "I personally favor in-person courses over online."

Tags: sentence-construction

Which of the following sentences is correct?
In fact, I'd like to know the position of adjectives and noun is correct or not. "in-person"  and "online" both are adjectives for "courses", now I'd like to know which arrangement of words in the following sentences is correct.

1. I personally favor in-person over online courses.
2. I personally favor in-person courses over online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either version is correct. It would not be wrong in both cases to repeat the word courses as well which ends up with the same version.

> I personally favor in-person courses over online courses

Of the two versions in the question I would find the first one more natural as the second sounds as though it has been cut off and I am left expecting something else to continue it but I think that is an issue of style not grammar.